# Counting number of swaps and Comparisons: Selection Sort

Tags: c#, sorting, count

I am trying to count number of swaps and comparisons that my selection sort algorithm makes. CountSwaps is a global variable.

I tried implementing the swap count in the actual swap method but it gives same output.

```
 public static void SelectionSort(int[] Array) // descending order
    {
        int countComps = 0;
        int max;
        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i <= Array.Length - 1; i++) // go through the list
        {
            countComps++;
            max = i; // maximum equals the current position in list
            for (int j = i + 1; j < Array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Array[j] > Array[max])
                    max = j; // max equals biggest in list j
            }
            countSwaps = 0;
            swap(Array, i, max); 
            countSwaps++;
        }           
        Console.WriteLine("Array after Basic Selection Sort");
        Display(Array);
        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time Taken for Basic Selection Sort is {0} milliseconds", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of swaps is : {0} ", countSwaps);
        Console.WriteLine("The number of comparisons is : {0} ", countComps);
```

My swap count gives an output value of 1 which is clearly wrong. 
My comparison count gives an output value of 5128 - this refers to the number of values in the textfile. I am sure comparisons is supposed to be number of values in list - 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a few mistakes here. For one thing, you're resetting countSwaps every time, which is why it doesn't count higher than one:

```
        …}
        countSwaps = 0; // <--------- here!
        swap(Array, i, max); …
```

Second, you're not counting the comparisons at all; you're counting the number of times the outer loop runs. You're supposed to increment countComps each time an actual comparison happens:

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j < Array.Length; j++)
        {
            ++countComps; <--------- here!
            if (Array[j] > Array[max])
                max = j; // max equals biggest in list j
        }
```

Selection sort is an O(n^2) sort and you're likely to get a few million comparisons for 5000 entries, which is a lot and which is why we generally don't use selection sort for large collections. An O(n*log n) sort such as merge sort will make something like 60k comparisons.

Comment: Thanks so much! I see my mistakes now